# Shortest, lexicographically smallest generating string

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, subsequence

A string `x` *generates* a string `y` if `y` is a substring of an infinite repeat of `x`.  For example `abc` generates `bcabcab`.

Write a program to find the shortest, lexicographically smallest string that will generate the input.  You are given on standard input a single line of text.  You should print the generating string to standard output.  For example:

**input**

```
bcabcabca
```

**output**

```
abc
```

Shortest code wins.  You may assume the input contains only the characters a-z (and a trailing newline if you want).

Comment: Output should be in any order? Say output can be `bac` in your example rather than `abc`?

Comment: @GroovyUser: no, the input is not a substring of a repeated pattern of `bac`s.

Comment: But the input _could_ consist of a substring of `(bca)^n`, which means `bca` is just as valid for the given example as `abc`.

Comment: @JAB: `bca` is not the smallest lexicographically.

Comment: Ah, I somehow missed that part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Ruby 1.9, 40 characters

```
gets;a=?a;a.next!until(a*~/$/)[$_];$><<a
```

Assumes the input is not terminated by a newline. Also it's probably ridiculously slow for larger results.

```
$ echo -n "bcabcabca" | ruby genlex.rb 
abc
$ echo -n "barfoobarfoobarfoo" | ruby1.9 genlex.rb 
arfoob
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python <s>88</s> 185 chars**

```
import re
s=raw_input()
m=s.index(min(s))
s=s[m:]+s[:m]
i=0
while s.replace(s[:i],''):i+=1
m=min(s[:i])
s=re.findall('%s[\w]*?(?=%s|$)'%(m,m),s[:i])
m=s.index(min(s))
print ''.join(s[m:]+s[:m])
```

Output:

```
bcabcabca
abc

aaa
a

abc
abc

cccbbcccbbcccbb
bbccc

barfoofoobarfoofoo
arfoofoob

bacabac
abacbac
```

Comment: Doesn't give you the lexicographically smallest string for some inputs, e.g. "bacabac"

Comment: @Howard You are right. I've updated my code, it is much longer now, but handles strings like `bacabac` correctly.

Comment: "abac" would be correct, see @yogsototh's answer: a**bacabac**abac.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell, <strike>299</strike> 128 characters

```
import Data.List
main=interact(\z->minimum$filter(\w->isInfixOf z$concat$replicate(length z)w) $filter((/=)"")$inits=<<tails z)
```

Thanks to jloy! Now the version is both far shorter and I believe correct.

Comment: So, the good news is that it's possible to golf this solution down to about 91 chars if you accept input on stdin as in Ventero's Ruby solution.  Unfortunately, the input `cabcabcabc` produces `abcabc`, so this solution isn't quite there.  I think you'll need to modify `q++q++q` in order to get the desired result.  My quick attempt at fixing bumped things back up to 145 chars though. (Spoilers are here: https://gist.github.com/1035161)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't knew about interact nor never though about inits <<= tails to get all substrings. I slightly modified your version to gain a bit of characters. I removed sort and changed filter(not.null) by filter((/=)""). Thanks again!

Comment: Why do you need `(/=)""` condition? It doesn't seem to do anything. Also, getting rid of lambdas helps: you can get rid of w altogether using `.` operator and change main function to `main=interact s` to save a couple of characters.

Comment: I think the answer for "bca" is wrong. It should be "abc", but is "bca" now.

Comment: One possible solution is to use `permutations` instead of `tails`.

Comment: @Rostor is correct about the null filter.  That was left over from an brief experiment with `cycle` and shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, <del>161 159 166 140 141 134</del> 132 chars

```
y=raw_input();i=n=l=len(y)
while i:
 if (y[:i]*l)[:l]==y:n=i
 i-=1
x=y[:n];y=x*2
while i<n:
 x=min(x,y[i:i+n])
 i+=1
print x
```

**EDIT** : Golfed the code after reading  Jules Olléon's comment. Removed a 'bug' that `bcdabcdab` results in `abbc`.

**EDIT2** : Fixed the bug (`abaa` results in `aaa`) spotted by Jules Olléon.

I don't know about Python well, so this code is probably 'not golfed'.

I love this rule:

*You may assume the input contains only the characters a-z...*

### Inputs & Outputs

```
bcdabcd
abcd

bcabcabca
abc


abcdabcd
abcd

bcdabcdab
abcd

barfoofoobarfoofoobar
arfoofoob

cccbbcccbbcccbb
bbccc

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
a

thequickbrownfox
brownfoxthequick

ababa
ab

abaa
aab
```

Comment: Brown fox, the quick! Dog, the lazy!

Comment: Nice solution, pretty short and probably the best complexity here! You could golf it a bit - for instance, you dont need "int" to compare strings; and replace "while i>0" by "while i" and "y=y+y" by "y*=2".

Comment: Actually there's a problem : for abaa it prints aaa...

Comment: @Jules Thanks for the comment! I didn't think about that one...

Comment: You can do `i-=1` instead of `i=i-1`. Likewise for the increment.

Answer (score 2):

**Python, <strike>121</strike> <strike>137</strike> 129 chars**

```
s=raw_input()
n=len(s)
l=[(s+s)[i/n:i/n+i%n+1]for i in range(n*n)]
print min(filter(lambda x:(x*len(s)).find(s)+1,sorted(l)),key=len)
```

EDIT: fixed the bug spotted by JiminP

Comment: Wow, it's great! Unfortunately, it prints `aabab` for string `ababa`... :(

Comment: Ok, fixed... it's getting longer :(

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby 1.9, 36

```
$><<(?a..gets).find{|s|(s*~/$/)[$_]}
```

Uses the same approach as Ventero's solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica 124 bytes

```
x = StringLength@(y = "");
For[i = 1, ! (s = y~StringTake~i)~StringRepeat~x~StringContainsQ~y,i++];
First@Sort@StringPartition[s <> s, i, 1]
```

Whitespace and newlines (in the presence of semicolons at the ends of lines) have no meaning in Mathematica and are included here for readability.

Input goes in between the quotation marks in the first line. If recast as a function, that takes string input like so:

```
f=(x=StringLength@(y=#);For[i=1,!(s=y~StringTake~i)~StringRepeat~x~StringContainsQ~y,i++];First@Sort@StringPartition[s<>s,i,1])&

f@"bca"

(* "abc" *)

f@"abaa"

(* "aab" *)
```

then it's 128 bytes.

The `For` loop takes the first `i` characters of the input and repeats them at least up to the length of the input, then checks if the input is a substring of the result. Having found the length of the period of the string, the `StringPartition` command concatenates two copies of that period and takes all substrings of that length from it (basically gets all cyclic permutations), then `First@Sort` finds the first one of them when lexicographically ordered.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 23 bytes

```powershell
-join($args|group|% N*)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9XzcrPzNPQyWxKL24Jr0ov7SgRlXBT0vzfy0Xl0pmHlCJelJyIgSpc6kBNTlk5v3/DwA)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Given input `abacaba` it gives `abc`, which could never generate the input...

Answer (score -1):

javascript 96 Chars.

```
var temp = {},len = str.length;
for(i in str) 
temp[str[i]] = true;
Object.keys(temp).join("");
```

[Working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CLFx07mLdSwU9iNDDp7d?p=preview)

Comment: Welcome to the community ! I couldn't test your code though, could you provide either code reading from GET/POST and writing with alert or console.log or a function taking the input as a parameter and returning the output?

Comment: @AaronGOUZIT added pluckr

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Still, the code you posted can't be used alone, so that cheats the byte count. More importantly, I'm afraid your code doesn't respect the specs : I believe you return a set of unique letters used rather than a "generating string", which we should be able to repeat (as a whole) with optional truncation to obtain the input. I'm looking forward to seeing your updated code !