# Check Lyndon word

Tags: code-golf, string

A [Lyndon word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word) is a string that is strictly [lexicographically smaller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) than any of its cyclic rotations. Given a binary string, determine if it's a Lyndon word in as few bytes as possible.

For example, `001011` is a Lyndon word. Its rotations, listed below, are obtained by repeatedly moving the first symbol to the end.

```
001011
010110
101100
011001
110010
100101
```

Of these, the original string comes lexicographically first, or equivalently, represents the smallest binary number.

However, `001001` is not a Lyndon word because one of its rotations is the same as itself, which ties it for lexicographically earliest.

[A related problem.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2862/20260)

**Input:** A non-empty binary string or list of digits `0` and `1`. You may *not* use numbers, like `5` to represent `101`.

**Output:** A consistent Truthy or Falsey value that says whether the string is a Lyndon word.

Built-ins specifically for Lyndon words are not allowed.

**Test cases:**

The Lyndon words with length up to 6 are:

```
0
1
01
001
011
0001
0011
0111
00001
00011
00101
00111
01011
01111
000001
000011
000101
000111
001011
001101
001111
010111
011111
```

The non-Lyndon words of length up to 4 are:

```
00
10
11
000
010
100
101
110
111
0000
0010
0100
0101
0110
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

**Leaderboard:**

```js
    var QUESTION_ID=62587,OVERRIDE_USER=20260;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/63075/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
    body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 42

It seems to be good enough to compare with suffixes instead of bothering with a rotation.

```
f=lambda s,i=1:i/len(s)or s<s[i:]*f(s,i+1)
```

The setup of the recursion does not seem very nice; maybe it could be done better.

This 44-byte version makes it more obvious what's going on:

```
lambda s:all(s<=s[i:]for i in range(len(s)))
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>43</s> 38 bytes

```
f x=all(x<=)$init$scanl(const.tail)x x
```

`scanl(const.tail)x x` builds a list of all suffixes of `x`, including the empty string `""` at the end, which is stripped off with `init`.

Edit: @feersum spotted a bug in my first version and [came up with the idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63086/34531) that comparing to suffixes is enough.

Comment: How does it check that there aren't any rotations of `x` that are equal to `x`?

Comment: @feersum: it doesn't. It's a bug. Fixed it. Thanks for finding out!

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
!f>z>zTUz
```

[Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21f%3Ez%3EzTUz&input=001011&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A01%0A001%0A011%0A0001%0A0011%0A0111%0A00%0A10%0A11%0A000%0A010%0A100%0A101%0A110%0A111%0A0000&debug=0)

Uses Vihan et. al.'s suffixes approach.

Comment: Dang it, I thought I was on to something there :p +1

Answer (score 3):

## J, 11 char

Outputs `1` on Lyndon words and `0` otherwise.

```
0=0({/:)<\.
```

`<\.` takes suffixes and then `/:` tells us how to sort them lexicographically. `{` takes the entry at the `0`-th index and `0=` checks if it's zero: if it is, we have a Lyndon word, because the biggest suffix wouldn't change place in a sort; if it's nonzero, it is not a Lyndon word, because some suffix is lexicographically earlier.

```
   0=0({/:)<\. '001011'
1
   0=0({/:)<\. '001001'
0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [ShapeScript](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/ShapeScript), <s>57</s> 47 bytes

```
0?1'@"2"@+"20"$""~"21"$""~@2?2?>1<*'3?_1-*!@#@#
```

I created ShapeScript for [this competition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62064). The [interpreter on GitHub](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/ShapeScript) has a slightly modified syntax.

[Try it online!](http://shapescript.tryitonline.net/#code=MD8xJ0AiMiJAKyIyMCIkIiJ-IjIxIiQiIn5AMj8yPz4xPConMz9fMS0qIUAjQCM=&input=MDExMTEx)

Comment: **Trivia:** This is my 700th PPCG answer.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
r_,,\fm<(f>1-!
```

Try [this fiddle](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r_%2C%2C%5Cfm%3C(f%3E1-!&input=001011) in the CJam interpreter or [verify all test cases](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B_%2C%2C%5Cfm%3C(f%3E1-!%7D%2F&input=0%0A1%0A01%0A001%0A011%0A0001%0A0011%0A0111%0A00001%0A00011%0A00101%0A00111%0A01011%0A01111%0A000001%0A000011%0A000101%0A000111%0A001011%0A001101%0A001111%0A010111%0A011111%0A00%0A10%0A11%0A000%0A010%0A100%0A101%0A110%0A111%0A0000%0A0010%0A0100%0A0101%0A0110%0A1000%0A1001%0A1010%0A1011%0A1100%0A1101%0A1110%0A1111) at once.

#### How it works

```
r              e# Read a token from STDIN.
 _,            e# Push the length of a copy.
   ,           e# Turn length L into [0 ... L-1].
    \fm<       e# Rotate the token 0, ..., and L-1 units to the left.
        (      e# Shift out the first rotation, i.e., the original token.
         f>    e# Compare all other rotations with this one.
           1-  e# Remove 1 from the resulting array of Booleans.
             ! e# Apply logical NOT to turn an empty array into 1, and a
               e# non-empty one into 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 10 bytes

```
xe»x«xS(i©
```

Very golf, much short. [Try it online](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/)

#### Explanation && Ungolfed

```
xe(#x<=xS(i))

xe(#      // Loop through x
          // Check if all iterations return true
    x <=  // Input is less than or equal to...
    xS(i) // Input chopped at current index
)
```

Comment: Holy cow, you're beating <s>Pyth</s> *Dennis*! How is this even possible?!

Comment: @ETHproductions In a world where Dennis can be [out-golfed](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/61929/the-combinatorics-of-transistor/62032#62032) anything is possible :p

Comment: I'll savor this moment while it lasts, then the CJam and Pyth answers will probably be golfed more

Comment: Wait, wait... I see that this properly handles cases like `00`, but how does it do this without catching on itself being equal to itself (i.e. when `i==0`)?

Comment: @ETHproductions This doesn't actually cycle much like feersum's [answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63086/40695), simply comparing the suffixes is functionally equivalent

Comment: Oh hey, you're right :) Let's see, that means I can golf about 10 bytes off my WIP Japt answer...

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 29

```haskell
f s=all(s<=)$init$scanr(:)[]s
```

Checks whether `s` is at most each of its non-empty suffixes, like [nimi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63080/20260).

The expression `scanr(:)[]` generates the list of suffixes by listing.

```haskell
>> scanr(:)[] "abcd"
["abcd","bcd","cd","d",""]
```

The `init` then gets rid of the empty string at the end. Finally, `all(s<=)` checks whether every suffix `x` satisfies `s<=x`. Since the first suffix is `s` itself, a `<=` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 37 bytes

```
->s{(1...s.size).all?{|i|s[i..-1]>s}}
```

Testing:

```ruby
lyndon_words = %w(0 1 01 001 011 0001 0011 0111 00001 00011 00101 00111
                  01011 01111 000001 000011 000101 000111 001011 001101
                  001111 010111 011111)

not_lyndon_words = %w(00 10 11 000 010 100 101 110 111 0000 0010 0100 0101
                      0110 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111)

f=->s{(1...s.size).all?{|i|s[i..-1]>s}}

p lyndon_words.all? &f      # => true
p not_lyndon_words.any? &f  # => false
```

Answer (score 1):

### Burlesque, 15 bytes

```
JiRJU_j<]x/==&&
```

Mainly 8 of those 7 bytes are to check if it doesn't tie. Otherwise you can go with simply `JiR<]==`.

**Explanation:**

```
J       -- duplicate word
iR      -- all rotations
J       -- duplicate list of all rotations
U_      -- check if list contains no duplicates
j       -- swap
<]      -- find minimum of the list
x/      -- rotate top
==      -- compare minimum with the original word
&&      -- and results of min == orig and list unique
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ẏvǔg=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuo92x5RnPSIsIiIsIlwiMDAxMDExXCIiXQ==)

```
 vǔ   # Rotate by each of...
ẏ     # 0 to len(x)
   g  # Does the (lexicographic) minimum
    = # Equal the input?
```

Comment: From the challenge description: "_However, `001001` is not a Lyndon word because one of its rotations is the same as itself, which ties it for lexicographically earliest._"

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 12 bytes

Hope to golf a little bit.

```
.A<Lzt.<Lzlz
```

[Try online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.A%3CLzt.%3CLzlz&input=001011&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A01%0A001%0A011%0A0001%0A0011%0A0111%0A00%0A10%0A11%0A000%0A010%0A100%0A101%0A110%0A111%0A0000&debug=0).

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6), 129 bytes

```
a=Array;s=prompt();console.log(a.from(a(s.length),(x,i)=>i).map(n=>(s.substring(n)+s.substring(0,n--))).sort().pop().contains(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, <s>91</s> 87 bytes

```
f=x=>(y=(x+x).slice(1,-1),x[0]==x||!(y.indexOf(x)+1)&&!x.indexOf('0')&&x.slice(-1)==1);
```

I'm basically concatenating the word with itself and check if it's still there.
To check if it is the smallest number possible, I just check that it start with a 0 and end with a 1.

#### Tests

```
[
['0',1],
['1',1],
['01',1],
['001',1],
['011',1],
['0001',1],
['0011',1],
['0111',1],
['00001',1],
['00011',1],
['00101',1],
['00111',1],
['01011',1],
['01111',1],
['000001',1],
['000011',1],
['000101',1],
['000111',1],
['001011',1],
['001101',1],
['001111',1],
['010111',1],
['011111',1],
['00',0],
['10',0],
['11',0],
['000',0],
['010',0],
['100',0],
['101',0],
['110',0],
['111',0],
['0000',0],
['0010',0],
['0100',0],
['0101',0],
['0110',0],
['1000',0],
['1001',0],
['1010',0],
['1011',0],
['1100',0],
['1101',0],
['1110',0],
['1111',0]
].forEach(t =>{ 
  r=f(t[0])
  x=t[1]
  console.log('Test '+(r==x?'OK':'Fail (Expected: ' + x +')')
  +'\nInput: '+t[0]+'\nResult: ' +r+'\n')                       
})
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 86 bytes

```
(s=Table[#~StringRotateLeft~i,{i,StringLength@#}];Last@s==First@Sort@s&&s~Count~#==1)&
```

**input**

> ["1111"]

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 85 bytes

```powershell
param($k)($w=0..($l=$k.Length-1)|%{-join$k[-$_..($l-$_)]}|sort)[0]-eq$k-and$w[1]-ne$k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZTdaoNAEIXvfYpFJkUhG3YfQAjkttDS9E4kWDNpGo2m7ooF47Pb1TQ/0BlvhHNmvzlnEU9Vi7XZY1HIrKpxgF3UDae0To8B5GEAbaQWiwCKCPLFM5afdi91eJ518lB9lZDHEjaT795h0p9NVdswVonEb8hlWm6hjXUiS4R86D1vGXjCPfNl4Ct/LsDWDYY3Sf@XFKWRoiYnmfM0gCYoBkyTuYXkRjYIk0RxCZmIbHQuOxOeLcW14mqRnFHbpYV5/BJIUROiIs8rGsDs0uQyOgKTgQxBp1Cai0yyNVeFkTVdkWnOVKe7MxfF3dTjdCjOYia6yQaLxq5Sg87GnxNmFrciErC5uDWaprBOeILdfdabzPh1vWqMrY4vHwd3LlleiOOzbrIMjRlBfwT3D7ovuM35744oRqQ/zt74V//tuv6KmZze673hFw)

1. Generates all the rotations of the input
2. Sorts them
3. Checks that the first one equals the input and the second one does not

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 (or 8?) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ā._{QJR
```

Outputs a 05AB1E truthy/falsey result, where truthy is a `1` padded with leading 0s up to the input-length, and falsey anything else. But since the challenge description mentions 'consistent' truthy/falsey value, a trailing `Θ` (05AB1E-truthify builtin: `==1`) can be added for consistent `1`/`0` outputs.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SKNefHWgV9D//wYGhkAEAA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R8SZOJzbsvhxafnKBkYGBoYGiqAKANDJeVDq8sq7ZUUHrVNUlCyr3T5f6RRL7460Cvov4t9ppKCRklRaUlGpabS4dVATlpiTnEqkFOr8x8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
ā        # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input-length] (without popping)
 ._      # Rotate the input that many times (vectorized) towards the left
   {     # Sort this list of rotations
    Q    # Check for each rotation whether it's equal to the (implicit) input
     J   # Join the checks together
      R  # Reverse this string
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```