# Smallest unused number sharing a factor

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, permutations

This is a pretty run of the mill question.  I will define a sequence and you golf some code to output a entry given a index.

- The first item in the sequence is 2.
- The nth item in the sequence is the smallest positive integer other than n and 1 sharing at least one factor with n (other than 1) that has not already appeared in the list.

## Test cases

Here are the first 25 items in the sequence:

```
1  2
2  4
3  6
4  8
5  10
6  3
7  14
8  12
9  15
10 5
11 22
12 9
13 26
14 7
15 18
16 20
17 34
18 16
19 38
20 24
21 27
22 11
23 46
24 21
25 30
```

[Related (offset by one) OEIS](http://oeis.org/A077127)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
R»2ɓ²Rg⁸>1Tḟ⁸ḟḢṭµ/Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/o0G6jk5MPbQpKf9S4w84w5OGO@UAGkHy4Y9HDnWsPbdV/uHPVfyPToENbj@453P6oaY37fwA)

Comment: I was so happy that I had you out-golfed on the [Lyndon word factorization](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127337/lyndon-word-factorization/127369) question but then you hit me with this... (in all seriousness though this is a great answer)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>118</strike> 117 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to [Cameron Aavik](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48436/cameron-aavik)!</sup>

```python
import math
def f(n,i=3):
 if n<2:return 2
 while 1:
  if math.gcd(n,i)>1>(i in map(f,range(n)))<i!=n:return i
  i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCoMwEETvfsU2pyyKEL2J@iVepCa6pW5CuqX069OkpadhZngvvOXw3KdEZ/BR4FzlqDbrwGluaOpxqIAc8NgN0cozMnQVvA66WzD5Kl9B2v26FQBnM2sC4rwG7Zq48m41I@JIl4n/DipkPZkUIrFotbBqb55YPyRqQqhBLaJylO7yguB8hK/4pzQNGJO16QM)

The code is pretty inefficient (it brute-forces a value that doesn't exist in the previous results, and calculates the previous results again on every new value), so it works properly but I wouldn't recommend running it on large numbers.

Comment: Small tip: You can save a newline by making it `def f(n,i=3):` and removing the `i=3` line

Comment: [115 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY3BDoIwEETvfMXKaSsNsXDDln/gDByIUFgjS1NrjF9fQU@TmbyZcZ@wbFzGSKvbfIB1CEsyThYssiRTysZcRJXAe6HHBI1WmqvG0BkPMJ9v44GJWtVIQLzXHVrpB54nZCGEppNhcaXMqAT8FF6e20YWfcu66KPzxAHTjtP8vhHjM3gkARmkXUh3ObzdEwF28/A7@E8rCUrt8/EL).

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>60</s> 59 bytes

EDIT:

- -1 byte: @xnor pointed out `all(/=x)` was shorter than `` x`notElem` ``.

`f` takes an integer and returns an integer.

```hs
f n=[x|x<-[2..],gcd x n>1||n<2,all(/=x)$n:map f[1..n-1]]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZ5ubWOAbr1FQlJlXopemGW2op2dkGPs/TSHPNrqipsJGN9pITy9WJz05RaFCIc/OsKYmz8ZIJzEnR0PftkJTJc8KqF8hDaQtT9cwNlZR0eD/fwA)

This is very exponential time, so TIO times out after 21, while my interpreted GHCi got up to 22 before I stopped it just now. The following 9 bytes longer version memorizing into a list easily goes up into the thousands:

```hs
f n=[x|x<-[2..],gcd x n>1||n<2,all(/=x)$n:take(n-1)l]!!0
l=f<$>[1..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZ5ubWOAbr1FQlJlXopemGW2op2doYGAQ@z9NIc82uqKmwkY32khPL1YnPTlFoUIhz86wpibPxkgnMSdHQ9@2QlMlz6okMTtVI0/XUDMnVlHRgCvHNs1GxQ5kUOz//wA)

- `f n` uses a list comprehension to generate candidates `x`, taking the first passing one with `!!0`.
- `gcd x n>1` checks that `x` and `n` have common factors.
- `||n<2` exempts `n==1` from the factor requirement.
- `all(/=x)$n:map f[1..n-1]` checks that `x` is neither `n` nor a preceding sequence element.

Comment: @WheatWizard Hm, probably no difference in that case. Just used to doing it by default. It's one of the few alphanumerical functions that has a fixity defined to fit well that way.

Comment: `all(/=x)$` is 1 shorter there

Answer (score 2):

No built-in for GCD in C#, so...

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>197 196</strike> 194 bytes

```cs
n=>{if(n<2)return 2;var p=new int[n-1];int i=0,a,b;for(;i<n-1;)p[i]=f(++i);for(i=2;;i++)if(n!=i){for(a=n,b=i;a*b>0;)if(a>b)a%=b;else b%=a;if(b!=1&a!=1&!System.Array.Exists(p,e=>e==i))return i;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDBasMwDL3vK9RCh72kpc3VUWCM9bSNQRk7lB7s1NkEqVNsp2sp@fbMDtu66iDLT9LjPZVuWjZW9xCirKVz8GqbDyt3NxE5DzmG89JTCYeGtvAsyTD@17oMxVidnNe72bI1ZU7GpxBSARUgmLauxdVsRHuDxZkqZvKMW@1bayATB2lhj0Z/xe21mS42IhRAOE9lqkTVWCYoD7jg@zVtsGJJQnzACTMhKEl45Bwh8XNEJZpUIQl5p4q5iD1ZKC4nqISunQY1QSkCqka4uJUxjX6M3FsrT7PHIznv2D7VWGgMrL9aSXRdL26ubTUW2KA3@FuI8OQI2TwUQdbV5L@DPTTGNbWevVvy@omMZuMXffRvpnV6u/qUVm@XsvTByxiSQJnAmAf6@KlY0HO5bDdUXf8N)

Once again, refrain from using this code to calculate numbers in the sequence for `n>30`...

- -1 byte by changing the GCD `while` loop for a `for` loop.
- -2 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen! Nice one!

Comment: `a>0&b>0` can be golfed to `a*b>0`

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 46 bytes

```apl
{⍺←2⋄1=⍵:2⋄(~∨/⍺∊∇¨⍳⍵-1)∧(1<⍺∨⍵)∧⍺≠⍵:⍺⋄⍵∇⍨1+⍺}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR727gJTRo@4WQ9tHvVutQCyNukcdK/RBMh1djzraD6141LsZKKdrqPmoY7mGoQ1YBii4FcQHcToXgLSCWN0tQBZQz6PeFYbaQIFaoDVg/RYA)